# Is there a common ballpark estimate for the percentage of an IC package that is taken up by the die?

Tags: integrated-circuit, die, silicon

Not a very technical question but I'm interested in finding out the average size of a 3-axis accelerometer die. I’m finding that the smaller package sizes are around 2x2x1mm, is there a way of estimating roughly what size the die would be for a IC package of that size?

The two IC’s I’ve come across are ‘0273.141.169-1NV Bosch’ & ‘MEMSensing Microsystems MSA300’ both of which are 2x2x1mm.

Could I estimate that the die would be approximately 80% of the package size for example? I’ve spent some time googling this with no answers. Does anyone have any experience with this, or do I need to decap/X-Ray the ICs?

Thanks in advances & Best Regards,

Jack

Comment: For some packages, such estimates make no sense at all, for others, you can do much better. What kind of packages are we talking about?

Comment: package sizes are often more defined by the number and size of desirable contacts than by the die size, but of course there's exceptions, like chip-scale packages, which, you guess it, are literally chips with a few balls underneath and otherwise lacquer all around.

Comment: But before you decap anything, have you checked for patents with "3-axis accelerometer" belonging to the manufacturers of these devices? Not like there's too much secret about the size, so there might be pretty enlightening drafts in there.

Comment: If the package is chip-scale, it’s the size of the chip itself. That’s probably the case with this device. A wire bond package needs about ~1mm around the edge.

Comment: Take the lids off.

Comment: It depends very strongly on the die and package in question. There are parts you can get with the same exact die in both SOIC and DIP, and sometimes TSSOP too.

Comment: @hacktastical having thought about this: micro-mechanical devices are probably *not* chip-scale-packageable, due to the need for mechanical protection from the top.

Comment: Here is what that Bosch part looks like inside: https://dokumen.tips/reader/f/bosch-3-axis-accelerometer-bma250-1-crm0742011-1bosch-3-axis-accelerometer

Comment: Interesting. So, 3D package using wirebond.

Comment: @DamienD Thanks for the link that was really useful, I did also stumble across this mini report thats quite a few years old but looking at the package sizes of modern equivelants they haven't changed much - https://memsblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/the-evolution-of-compact-three-axis-accelerometers/

Comment: @Hearth having looked though a bunch of X-Rayed IC's now I understand your point more, the packages I've looked at tend to be LGA and seem to often use stacked die's especially on the 2x2x1mm sized packages.

Comment: @JackSoldano Multiple stacked dice is kind of unusual; you certainly almost never see it in the types of devices I work on (power electronics). It would make heat dissipation far too difficult.